# Function look-up in clojure

Tags: clojure

Help me I need to write look up function that finds value in the list-of-lists in that every element is in order (key value).
For example

```
((key1 value1) (key2 value2) ....)
```

This function needs to be

```
(look-up key list-of-lists)
```

And returns value of the list that has key.
For example:

```
(look-up b '(((a b) 1) (c 2) (b 3)))3
(look-up (a b) '(((a b) 1) (c 2) (b 3)))1
(look-up d '(((a b) 1) (c 2) (b 3)))nil
```

I have this code:

```
(defn look-up [key list-of-lists]
  (if (= key (first(first list-of-lists))) (second(first list-of-lists)))
  (:else (look-up (rest list-of-lists key))))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(defn lookup [x xs]
  (first (for [[k v] xs :when (= k x)]
           v)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple version that works:

```
(defn lookup
  [k lol]
  (let [the-map (into {}
                  (for [lst lol]
                    {(first lst) (second lst) } ))
        result (get the-map k)]
    result ) )

(lookup (quote b)      (quote (((a b) 1) (c 2) (b 3)))) => 3
(lookup (quote [a b])  (quote (((a b) 1) (c 2) (b 3)))) => 1
(lookup (quote d)      (quote (((a b) 1) (c 2) (b 3)))) => nil
```

---

However, your code will be simpler if you replace all of the quoted lists like `'(1 2 3)` with vectors like `[1 2 3]` (don't need the leading quote then), and replace all quoted symbols like `'a` with keywords like `:a` (also don't need to quote the symbols.

Making these changes and adding unit tests looks like so:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core demo.core tupelo.test) )

(defn lookup
  [k lol]
  (get (into {} lol) k))

(dotest
  (is= 3    (lookup :b      [[[:a :b] 1] [:c 2] [:b 3]]))
  (is= 1    (lookup [:a :b] [[[:a :b] 1] [:c 2] [:b 3]]))
  (is= nil  (lookup :d      [[[:a :b] 1] [:c 2] [:b 3]])))
```

---

P.S.  Please [see Brave Clojure](https://www.braveclojure.com/) for more details.

---

**Update:**

Your cannot use a regular function with this syntax:

```
(look-up b '(((a b) 1) (c 2) (b 3)))
```

since `b` is a symbol and is meant to be a **variable**, not a **piece of data**.  Your choices:

1. Convert the symbol `b` to a keyword `:b` as I suggested
2. Always quote the symbol like `'b` (painful & error-prone)
3. Write a macro (which automatically "quotes" all its args), and have the macro call the 1st version of the `lookup` function (a lot of work for small benefit).

That is way I suggested item (1) as the preferred solution.

Comment: Suggest you replace the map in`(for [lst lol] {(first lst) (second lst)})` with a vector. The fact that a single-entry map can function as a map entry here is surely an accident.

Comment: It is not acting as a MapEntry.  Into can merge a sequence of maps:  `(into {} [{:a 1, :b 2} {:c 3, :d 4}]) => {:a 1, :b 2, :c 3, :d 4}`.  In fact, it is Clojure's special treatment of a 2-vector as a faux `MapEntry` that is kludgy.

Comment: Don't agree. Docs say `(into to-coll from-coll)` *Returns a new coll consisting of `to-coll` with all of the items of `from-coll` conjoined*. The core implementation is wrong. If Clojure were statically typed, the error would be blatant.

Comment: Unfortunately, the docstring may give the wrong impression. The operative line from the source code is `(reduce conj to from)`.

Comment: Yes. The problem is with `conj`: `(conj {1 2} {3 4, 5 6})` producing `{1 2, 3 4, 5 6}` is wrong. The signature ought to be `coll [X] X -> coll [X]`. Again, static typing would expose the inconsistency. I wonder what the core spec has to say.

Comment: Yes, `conj` is a bit of a chameleon.  With vectors, it means "append 1 item".  With lists, it means "prepend 1 item".  With maps (& sets), it means "merge together".  I would have preferred 3 different functions `append`, `prepend`, and `glue`.

Comment: The docstring confirms my view. And if you think of a map as a set of (constrained) ordered pairs, what you `conj` to it ought to be an ordered pair. It seems to be an accident that you can `conj` a map to a map. And I think the contract for sequential collections is `(= (pop (conj coll x) coll)` and `(= (peek (conj coll x) x)`.

Comment: I'd be careful with using this map-based approach: you'll get surprising results if the input list contains any duplicated keys. Plus, it isn't lazy: it consumes the entire input sequence and builds a giant map out of it even if the item you're looking for is the very first one!

Answer (score 2):

Just a little bit of pattern matching...

```
(require '[meander.match.alpha :as pm])
(letfn [(lookup [KEY LIST]
            (pm/find LIST
                     (_ ... (~KEY ?v) . _ ...) ?v))]
    (let [LIST '(((a b) 1) (c 2) (b 3))]
        [(lookup 'b LIST)
         (lookup '(a b) LIST)
         (lookup 'd LIST)]))
=> [3 1 nil]
```

This is an overkill for such a simple case, but it is here to give a clue for some more advanced use cases.

Answer (score 1):

Your code was almost correct. The two things I fixed were:

- The syntax for "if" takes 3 arguments: a test and two values (for each boolean result of the test). There's no need for `:else` (generally that's used to highlight a default branch when using `cond`.
- The recursive call to continue looking at the rest of the list-of-lists had the arguments in the wrong order.

The corrected function looks like:

```
(defn look-up [key list-of-lists]                                                                                                                                                    
  (if (= key (first (first list-of-lists)))                                                                                                                                          
    (second (first list-of-lists))                                                                                                                                                   
    (look-up key (rest list-of-lists))))                                                                                                                                             

;; (look-up 'b '(((a b) 1) (c 2) (b 3))) ;; => returns 3
```

Note:

- You can simplify this code with other functions such as `ffirst`, see https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/ffirst
- You still need to improve it to cover these cases: 1.- [empty list](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/seq) and 2.- looking for a key that is not present. What would happen if you call `(look-up 'x '(((a b) 1) (c 2) (b 3)))` ?

Comment: For this example (look-up 'x '(((a b) 1) (c 2) (b 3))) result needs to be nil, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: The simplest change to solve both issues would be to check if there are any elements left on the list. If there are none, it was empty from the beginning or you've examined it all. In this case, something like wrapping the `if` with a check for the list not being empty: `(defn look-up [key list-of-lists] (if-not (empty? list-of-lists) (if (= key ...`

Answer (score 0):

You want to find the first item in the list that meets some criteria (check the item's first element), then you want to do something to that item (get its second element).

The [Clojure cheatsheet](https://clojure.org/api/cheatsheet) recommends `some` or `filter` for searching a seq.

- **some**

```clj
(defn lookup
  [x col]
  (some (fn [[k v]]
          (when (= x k) v))
        col))
```

- **filter**

```clj
(defn lookup
  [x col]
  (->> col
       (filter (fn [[k v]]
                 (when (= x k) v)))
       first))
```

- **list comprehension**

Also a good option. See [amalloy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54281304/2472391).

- **generic solution if you want to get crazy**

You could use any of the above methods to do this.

```clj
(defn lookup
  [pred f col]
  (some (fn [x]
          (when (pred x)
            (f x)))
       col))

(defn lookup
  [pred f col]
  (first (for [x col :when (pred x)]
           (f x))))

;; usage: (lookup (comp '#{b} first) second data)
```